# Detail Object not available in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, master-detail

I have an Object- Foo( Master ) and an Object- Hoo(Detail). Hoo is a child of Foo and related by a Master Detail Relationship. I am creating a test class where I need to access Hoo object from Foo. In my Test class I created:

```
Foo__c parentobj = new Foo__c();
Insert parentobj ;
Hoo__c childtest = new Hoo__c();
childtest.Foo__c=parentobj.id; // Foo__c is the Master-detailAPI name on Hoo object
Insert childtest;
system.debug(****child record*****+ childObj.Name); // This is NULL , why?
system.debug('**** print Children size ***+ parentobj.Hoo__r.size() );
// I get an output - 0 ( means no child, but I just assigned it above)
```

Not sure why this behaviour or what am I doing wrong here. Appreciate some insights.

Debug log:

```
02:50:28.0 (285914840)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[24]|Aggregations:1|SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Hoo__r ) FROM Foo__c WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
02:50:28.0 (294142032)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[24]|Rows:1
02:50:28.0 (294573090)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[25]|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
```

Comment: ahh you need to query child records first then check in debug logs

Comment: Pls see my edit. I printed childobj.Name it is NULL. I do Insert childObj , what happened to that? Any Idea?

Comment: Rdvsm if name is auto generated field then it will be populated by salesforce so you need to get that value using soql query because in current  `parentobj` you are not mentioning the Name field it will be null..

Comment: Won't the Name get created when I create a new parentobj?

Comment: Yes Name will be generated but in order to get that value you need query..

Comment: How does querying would help here? The Childobj is still NULL right? Do I have to query the Name and then assign it to Childobj.Name? Appreciate if you can give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `Foo__c` Name field is auto number

```
Foo__c parentobj = new Foo__c();
Insert parentobj ;

//check name field is not null
System.assert([SELECT Name FROM Foo__c WHERE Id =: parentobj.Id].Name != null);

Hoo__c childtest = new Hoo__c();
//childtest.Foo__c=testobj.id; // Foo__c is the Master-detailAPI name on Hoo object
childtest.Foo__c = parentobj.id;
Insert childObj;

// check child record size is 1
List<Foo__c> lstFoo = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Hoo__r) FROM Foo__c 
                        WHERE Id =: parentobj.Id];
System.assert(lstFoo[0].Hoo__r.size() == 1);
```

Here Hoo__r is relationship name..

Comment: Thanks. The first assertion passed but the 2nd one failed. What does that mean? I use childtest.Foo__c=testobj.id; // Foo__c is the Master-detailAPI name on Hoo object to assign the Foo__c field on Hoo object. Should I use the API Name or child relationship Name(__r) ?

Comment: Yes I used relation ship name in the inner query. The 2nd one failed. The Name field on Parentobj is an auto number , should I use childtest.Foo__c=testobj.id; or childtest.Foo__c=testobj.Name; ? I am wondering why are you doing assert since my debug already shows that childObj.Name is NULL and parentobj.Hoo__r.size() is zero. Thanks

Comment: @Rdvsm Can you please add in your question what you have tried so far ? let me check once..

Comment: Your code above is what I have tried so far. I am not sure when I do childtest.Foo__c=testobj.id; , does the childtest object has the master record associated with it?

Comment: @Rdvsm check my updates.. try like that

Comment: Ratan, the assertion failed. Any idea , what is going wrong?

Comment: @Rdvsm ahh there is one mistake in my code while creating child record we need to mentioned parent Id that is `parentobj.Id` but we mentioned `testobj.id`.... If still getting error then may be child record is getting deleted from some where else just assumption

Comment: I don't think So Ratan, because I am using the correct object at correct place, I am using your code as a template and replacing it with actual object names and object in my code.

Comment: pls see my edit with the debug log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39257/discussion-between-ratan-and-rdvsm).